# Binding Image's Source in XAML DataTemplate to a URI in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, binding

Okay, what I'm trying to create is a list of images (using a listbox) with a thumbnail on the left, and image title on the right. My XAML is set up this way:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,6" Name="CurrentPhotos" Width="184" SelectionChanged="CurrentPhotos_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FilePathConverter}}" />
                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Title}"></sdk:Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I've got the FilePathConverter key defined in App.xaml and the code is set up:

```
public class FilePathConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(string))
        {
            return (value as PhotoSummary).FullThumbPath();
        }
        else
        {
            return (value as PhotoSummary).Thumb();
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There are breakpoints in both Convert and ConvertBack methods. ConvertBack never gets fired (so there's no exception etc.), and in Convert method, the Thumb returns correctly (string input is left for some test reasons, and not currently used. it's not fired anyways), and the Thumb extension method is this:

```
public static object Thumb(this PhotoSummary ps)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://" + Settings.Host + "/Content/Thumbs/" + ps.Uploaded.Year + "/" + ps.Uploaded.Month + "/" + ps.ID + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
    return new BitmapImage(uri);
}
```

This one gets called, and the Uri is built up correctly (tested several times). However, when I run the app, the list only contains the Title of the photo, and no image is there. All the images are small (they are just thumbs), local files, so they need to load up instantly so it's not a loading issue either. But it's as if there's no Image tag there. It just displays the labels of the photos. Converter is working, Uri is correct, there are no errors at all, but no image shows up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to verify if silverlight is really making a request for the image and if the image is really being returned?

Comment: Tried, and no, no requests are made. I can see other requests from the same app (service calls), they work and I can see them in Fiddler, but no image requests. Quite weird.

Comment: Hrm odd, maybe try subscribing to the ImageFailed event on an Image to see if theres some problem parsing the Uri that prevents the download from starting.

Comment: Another thought, check the Image ActualWidth/ActualHeight and make sure they're non-zero, maybe try setting Width/Height to a value to see if the images aren't downloaded because its given no space to show an image in the stackpanel.

Comment: I would use Silverlight Spy to see what's going on in the visual tree, and make sure that the ImageSource is getting set properly on the images.  Also check the dimensions of the image, as per MerickOWA's comment.

Comment: I am getting an exception in the image failed event handler, it's just a System.Exception and the message says AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR and nothing else. No inner esception or anything. Investigating now.

Comment: Solved. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem was about a security restriction in SL. It was running locally, and making a call to http://localhost... was failing due to security restriction (at least, for images). I've read that if I made a test page, launch from the local server etc. and then run it, the error would go away, but instead of that workaround, I just checked require elevated trust, and it suddenly started to work. So question is solved.

Comment: Maybe then another solution is to use relative URLs if possible rather than absolute?

Comment: well, I don't think that would create a difference. in the end, the url to be called is the same URL anyway. I also have the clientaccesspolicy.xml but that didn't work too so there's something else with that. for some other reasons, absolute uri is mure suitable for my project than relative.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to load the image explicitly in your converter. The [MSDN page for BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) shows the following code snippet:

```
// Create the image element.
Image simpleImage = new Image();    
simpleImage.Width = 200;
simpleImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

// Create source.
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"/sampleImages/cherries_larger.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
// Set the image source.


simpleImage.Source = bi;
```

Comment: That might work (although this code sample is for WPF not SL as there's no Begin/End init in SL), but I'm trying to achieve it "the declarative way", in pure XAML (at least, in mostly XAML as possible)

Answer (score 0):

Im using this for exactly same problem, But Im using Silverlight 5 with eleated trust, dont know it that matters

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            <Image Margin="0" Width="25" Height="25" Source="{Binding EventType, StringFormat=/Icons/EventType\{0:d\}.png}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And it works well. Its data template for DataGrid, where this EventType is enum of types.

this is what fiddler shows later

```
http://www.localdomain.loc/ClientBin/Icons/EventType1.png
```